# Enabling Analytics in WSO2 APIM throws DataEndpointAuthenticationException

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Enabled Analytics as per the [WSO2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#bac6f4f2481548aeab17878dd8646373) and can see the log 
`INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}` but keep getting DataEndpointAuthenticationException every 30sec

Setup is simple architecture where all the APIM modules are running on a given instance with Mysql db

```
==> logs/wso2carbon.log <==
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-13 14:53:53,372]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} -  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup}

==> logs/wso2-apigw-errors.log <==
2019-06-13 14:53:53,372 [-] [DataBridge-ReconnectionService-pool-8-thread-1]  WARN DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec

==> logs/wso2carbon.log <==
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-13 14:53:53,374] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:126)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:64)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)


==> logs/wso2-apigw-errors.log <==
2019-06-13 14:53:53,374 [-] [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://localhost:7612-pool-11-thread-1] ERROR DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
```

APIM analytics section say its not configured and the only way this error goes away is by disabling analytics.

Comment: Was there any startup errors in analytics server logs?

Comment: Above is the only error observed. Also I havent setup a separate analytics server, the setup is Single node (all-in-one) deployment, [Pattern1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Deployment+Patterns#DeploymentPatterns-Pattern1). I assume it contains the analytics module! Is my assumption wrong and I need to set one up?

Comment: Yes analytics is in a seperate server, you have to set up the APIM-M analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics is in separate server, download and start the API-M analytics server along with API-M server